# how to split the array list in separate array by day wise using javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

how to split the array list by days

```
const days = [
    {'name':'Mon','value':1}, 
    {'name':'Tue','value':5},
    {'name':'Wed','value':10},
    {'name':'Wed','value':30},
    {'name':'Fri','value':18},
    {'name':'Sat','value':80},
    {'name':'Sat','value':90},
    {'name':'Sun','value':20},
]
```

I having the above array list by days i **wed** and **Sat** i am having two values for **thu** I am not having values. i need to split the repeated key values into separate array if day are not in the list i need to add **zero value** for that for example my out put will be

```
const result = [
  [1,5,10,0,18,80,20],
  [0,0,30,0,0,90,0]
]
```

I need like this result is it possible to do in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `native` javascript.

The algorithm is very simple:

1. For each day in `daysArray` you should search it in your given array and just `remove` first occurence from `days`.
2. Do **step** 1 until `days` is empty. With the other words, execute step 1 until `days.length == 0` condition is satisfied.

```js
let days = [ {'name':'Mon','value':1}, {'name':'Tue','value':5}, {'name':'Wed','value':10}, {'name':'Wed','value':30}, {'name':'Fri','value':18}, {'name':'Sat','value':80}, {'name':'Sat','value':90}, {'name':'Sun','value':20} ], daysArray = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'];
let result = [];
while(days.length){
  sub_array = [];
  daysArray.forEach(function(item){
     let index = days.findIndex(a => a.name == item);
     if(index == -1)
         sub_array.push(0);
     else{
         sub_array.push(days[index].value);
         days.splice(index, 1); 
     }  
  });
  result.push(sub_array);
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an array of days in the order that you want - `daysList`.

Group the day objects into a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) using the name as key - `daysMap`.

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the `daysList`, and get the days objects from the map by the current day. Iterate the array of days with [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), and for each add a week array [filled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) with 0s if missing, and assign the day's value to the day index `di`.

```js
const daysList = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]

const days = [{"name":"Mon","value":1},{"name":"Tue","value":5},{"name":"Wed","value":10},{"name":"Wed","value":30},{"name":"Fri","value":18},{"name":"Sat","value":80},{"name":"Sat","value":90},{"name":"Sun","value":20}]

// group the days by name into a map
const daysMap = days.reduce((m, o) => {
  m.has(o.name) || m.set(o.name, [])
  
  m.get(o.name).push(o)

  return m
}, new Map)

// iterate the daysList
const result = daysList.reduce((r, d, di) => {
  //get the array of the days with the same name from the group
  const daysObjs = daysMap.get(d) || []
  
  //iterate the daysObjs array
  daysObjs.forEach(({ name, value }, wi) => {
    // add a new week array filled with 0 if the row is missing
    r[wi] || r.push(new Array(daysList.length).fill(0))
    
    // assign the day value to the week array
    r[wi][di] = value
  })
  
  return r
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take an object for the day indices and for the ouiter indixec which is incremented by every inset of data.

```js
var days = [{ name: 'Mon', value: 1 }, { name: 'Tue', value: 5 }, { name: 'Wed', value: 10 }, { name: 'Wed', value: 30 }, { name: 'Fri', value: 18 }, { name: 'Sat', value: 80 }, { name: 'Sat', value: 90 }, { name: 'Sun', value: 20 }],
    indices = { Mon: { day: 0, index: 0 }, Tue: { day: 1, index: 0 }, Wed: { day: 2, index: 0 }, Thu: { day: 3, index: 0 }, Fri: { day: 4, index: 0 }, Sat: { day: 5, index: 0 }, Sun: { day: 6, index: 0 } },
    result = days.reduce((r, { name, value }) => {
        r[indices[name].index] = r[indices[name].index] || Array.from({ length: 7 }).fill(0);
        r[indices[name].index++][indices[name].day] = value;
        return r;
    }, []);
   
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice. I like how you've solved the row index problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#reduce` and a lookup object of day and create an array of `value` based on a given day.

```js
const days = [{'name':'Mon','value':1}, {'name':'Tue','value':5}, {'name':'Wed','value':10}, {'name':'Wed','value':30}, {'name':'Fri','value':18}, {'name':'Sat','value':80}, {'name':'Sat','value':90}, {'name':'Sun','value':20}, ],
  day = {'Mon':0, 'Tue':1, 'Wed':2, 'Thu': 3, 'Fri': 4, 'Sat': 5, 'Sun': 6},
  result = days.reduce((r,o) => {
    var index = 0;
    if(r[index][day[o.name]]) {
      while(r[index] && r[index][day[o.name]]) {
        index++;
      }
      if(!r[index]) {
        r[index] = Array.from({length: 7}, _=> 0);
      }
    } 
    r[index][day[o.name]] = o.value;
    return r;
},[Array.from({length: 7}, _=> 0)]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution:

```
const res = _.chain(days)
    .map('name') // get days name
    .uniq() // uniq days name
    .map(day => _.filter(days, { name: day })) // iterate days name and get all day items
    .map(sameDays => _.map(sameDays, 'value')) // get value for each day items
    .map(vs => [vs[0], vs[1] || 0]) // set 0 value if only one item for day
    .thru(_.spread(_.zip)) // transpose the array
    .value()
```